# Issue with z-index in nivo slider caption

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to bring "nivo slider caption" to top but i can't.
i made a fiddle from my html structure and css code. 
if you click on caption, javascript will alert elements properties where you clicked, but it can not find caption.
please help!
http://jsfiddle.net/BbHn4/

```
<div id="sliderWrap">
  <div class="slider-wrapper theme-h0mayun">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" style="z-index:-1000">
      <img src="images/slider/176110test.png" data-thumb="images/slider/176110test.png" alt="" title="test" style="width: 850px; visibility: hidden; display: inline">
      <img class="nivo-main-image" src="images/slider/176110test.png" style="display: inline; width: 850px; height: auto">
      <div class="nivo-caption" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 390px; left: 0px">test</div>
      <div class="nivo-directionNav">
        <a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a>
        <a class="nivo-nextNav">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nivo-controlNav">
      <a class="nivo-control active" rel="0">1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#slider { 
background-color: #2E4ADC;
background-position: 50% 50%;
border: 5px solid #295C94;
border-radius: 15px;
position: absolute;
}

#slider { 
z-index: -1 !important;
}
.theme-h0mayun .nivoSlider { 
background: url() 50% 50% no-repeat #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4A4A4A;
height: 430px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 550px;
}

.nivoSlider { 
height: 300px;
margin: 0px auto 0px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 900px;
}
.theme-h0mayun .nivoSlider img { 
display: none;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}

.nivoSlider img { 
left: 0px;
max-width: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}

.nivoSlider { 
z-index: -1;
}

.nivo-caption { 
background: #000000;
bottom: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: none;
left: 0px;
opacity: 0.8;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 5px 10px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 8;
}

.nivo-caption { 
height: 40px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
z-index: 2000000 !important;
}
```

one thing i should add is that caption position should be absolute as my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all your z-index stuff that is less than 0.  You are shoving everything into the background.  Z-index works in stacks, so since the parent of .nivo-caption is less than 0, it is placed in the background.  All the children of that will also be in the background no matter what the z-index you give it.  Also, your alert for class is incorrect, you are alerting the ID twice.

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BbHn4/1/

```
<div id="sliderWrap">
  <div class="slider-wrapper theme-h0mayun">
    <div class="ribbon"></div>
    <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
      <img src="images/slider/176110test.png" data-thumb="images/slider/176110test.png" alt="" title="test" style="width: 850px; visibility: hidden; display: inline">
      <img class="nivo-main-image" src="images/slider/176110test.png" style="display: inline; width: 850px; height: auto">
      <div class="nivo-caption" style="display: block; position: absolute; top: 390px; left: 0px">test</div>
      <div class="nivo-directionNav">
        <a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a>
        <a class="nivo-nextNav">Next</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nivo-controlNav">
      <a class="nivo-control active" rel="0">1</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

#slider { 
background-color: #2E4ADC;
background-position: 50% 50%;
border: 5px solid #295C94;
border-radius: 15px;
position: absolute;
}

.theme-h0mayun .nivoSlider { 
background: url() 50% 50% no-repeat #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px #4A4A4A;
height: 430px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 550px;
}

.nivoSlider { 
height: 300px;
margin: 0px auto 0px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 900px;
}
.theme-h0mayun .nivoSlider img { 
display: none;
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}

.nivoSlider img { 
left: 0px;
max-width: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
}

.nivo-caption { 
background: #000000;
bottom: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: #FFFFFF;
display: none;
left: 0px;
opacity: 0.8;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 5px 10px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 8;
}

.nivo-caption { 
height: 40px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
z-index: 2000000 !important;
}
```

Comment: This link might help you understand better what is going on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_context_example_2

Comment: it doesn't work still in my main page
i removed all css codes and replace with yours but still #slider is in top :(((

Comment: Then you have other issues on your main page that you didn't post.  You are likely creating multiple z-index stacks by using position:relative and position:absolute.